# mysqli query to check email existance

Tags: php

i am trying for mysqli query, so that if email already exist, php will echo email is already exist. but not success
here is my snippet of code. i am totally new in php.
thank you for your help.

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT FROM talibeilm_1 WHERE email='$email'");
$res_e = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
 if (mysqli_num_rows($res_e) > 0)
  {
      echo "email already exists";
  }
else {
mysqli_select_db('hussain', $conn);
$sql="insert into talibeilm_1(firstname,lastname,email,gender)
VALUES('$firstname','$lastname','$email','$gender')";
}

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Query is already executed, you are trying to execute the query result now. Please have a look on doc [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) for more information.

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id FROM talibeilm_1 WHERE email='$email'");
// no need for below line, query is already executed.
// $res_e = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)
{
    echo "email already exists";
}
```

Comment: thank  you for your answer and error i am getting is that my browser telling that here is a problem in parameres and i am knowing not how to set it.

Comment: 'SELECT FROM' columns missed

Comment: please check updated query. Also post the error you are getting so we can help you. @OtoShavadze thanks , I have added column.